# Methods to protect a bottle.py webapplication against XSS and CSRF?

Tags: python, security, wsgi, bottle

I'm writing a webapplication using `bottle.py`, `Beaker` for sessions and a custom AAA written module, as many I'm worried about security and the best method to protect against some targeted attack like the one I've mentioned.

As an example I have the following code:

```
@route('/manage/adddomain',method='POST')
def adddomain():
    #This checks if user has enough power to create a domain
    aaa.require(50,'/forbidden') 

    user = aaa.getusername() # This is retrieved from a server side session
    domainname = request.forms.get('domain')
    description = request.forms.get('description')

    # Additional checks are performed in the sql module 
    # to protect against forged requests with valid login
    return sql.createdomain(user,domainname,description)
```

What additional checks would you perform to secure your webapplication?

Answer (score 4):

**Blender** pretty much covered what you need, but I would like to add another method. Instead of checking on each POST, you can add a wrapper like:

```
def wrap_requires_csrf(*methods):
    def wrapper(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            if request.method in methods:
                if request.method == 'POST':
                    csrf = request.form.get('csrf')
                elif request.method == 'GET':
                    csrf = request.args.get('csrf')
                if not csrf or csrf != session.get('csrf'):
                    abort(400)
                session['csrf'] = generate_csrf_token()
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return wrapper

@app.route('/some/page', methods=['GET','POST'])
@wrap_requires_csrf('POST')
def some_page():
    ...
```

Then, in your template, you would provide the hidden field with

```
<input name="csrf" type="hidden" name="{{session.csrf}}" />
```

Comment: Nice and comes as a decorator :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to include a CSRF token in every important form field and sanitize all output with your template engine.

Here's a [Flask snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/3/) that you can adapt to your Bottle app:

> A common technique against [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSRF) attacks is to add a random string
>   to the session, and check that string against a hidden field in the
>   POST.
>
> ```
> @app.before_request
> def csrf_protect():
>     if request.method == "POST":
>         token = session.pop('_csrf_token', None)
>         if not token or token != request.form.get('_csrf_token'):
>             abort(403)
>
> def generate_csrf_token():
>     if '_csrf_token' not in session:
>         session['_csrf_token'] = some_random_string()
>     return session['_csrf_token']
>
> app.jinja_env.globals['csrf_token'] = generate_csrf_token
> ```
>
> And then in your template:
>
> ```
> <form method=post action="">
>     <input name=_csrf_token type=hidden value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
> ```

As for sanitizing, that's dependent upon your template engine. Jinja2 has the `e` or `escape` filter:

```
<h2>No results for {{ search_query|escape }}</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I adapted **@Blender**'s solution to bottle, and here it is:

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits
from random import choice
from bottle import Bottle, request, Jinja2Template, abort

app = Bottle()

@app.hook('before_request')
def csrf_protect():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sess = request.environ['beaker.session']
        req_token = request.forms.get('csrf_token')

        # if no token is in session or it doesn't match the request one, abort
        if 'csrf_token' not in sess or sess['csrf_token'] != req_token:
            abort(403)

def str_random(length):
    '''Generate a random string using range [a-zA-Z0-9].'''
    chars = ascii_letters + digits
    return ''.join([choice(chars) for i in range(length)])

def gen_token():
    '''Put a generated token in session if none exist and return it.'''
    sess = request.environ['beaker.session']
    if 'csrf_token' not in sess:
        sess['csrf_token'] = str_random(32)
    return sess['csrf_token']

# allow access of the token generator using csrf_token
Jinja2Template.defaults['csrf_token'] = gen_token
```

Bottle does not come with sessions by default, so I'm using [bottle-beaker](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle-beaker).

The input which needs to be included in every form:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```